# Rspec "click_link" not working consistently

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I have a number of Rspec tests that require `click_link`... the problem is this doesn't work consistently. Here's a basic example of one of my tests

```
describe "user log in" do
  it "allows an existing user to sign in and make an appointment", js: true do 
  visit "/users/sign_in"

    fill_in "Login", with: "location"
    fill_in "Password", with: "ilovemonkeys"

    click_button "Sign in"
    click_link "Check-in"
  end
end
```

Sometimes the test will find the link and pass with flying colors and sometimes it will not find it at all. What is causing this inconsistency with `click_link` ?

Here are the gems I use

```
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.1'
  gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.5.1'
  gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
```

Comment: I'd suggest putting a `save_and_open_page` prior to the `click_link` call to see what the page looks like at that point. Hopefully, the error will still occur with the added delay.

Comment: Is the 'sign in' button and 'check in' links on two completely different screens?  You should add some kind of rspec expectation in between the two steps to add some consistency to your test.